# Browser extension refused to load image because it violates the img-src content security policy

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am working on a browser extension that uses a lot of images (it's a game with over 100MB of external images) so I am storing the spritesheets on my server. However on certain websites (like github.com and aclu.org so far) I cannot load the external resources. This is the error in the console...

[image: console]

The problem is that Github et al have a strict CSP policy for img files (even though [the W3C advises they shouldn't](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#extensions) and now I'm trying to figure out how to fix it. Here's what I tried to fix the issue:

1. Changing my extension manifest policy (per [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) and [this site](https://content-security-policy.com/)) to look like:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; img-src * data:;"
```

2. Adding `"<all_urls>"` to my manifest.permissions
3. Trying to load the image from localhost, 127.0.0.1, or API server domain.
4. Trying to load the image using `img` (`src=path`), css (`background-image: url(path)`)
5. Trying to [bypass the pages' CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions) load the image with an injected script or dom node [per this site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). You can repeat the issue on any Github page by adding the below into the console:

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
```

or using CSS

```js
document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:absolute;z-index:999999;top:0;left:0;width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;background-image: url(\'http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png\');">Hello </div>';
```

Comment: CSP in manifest.json has no influence on site's CSP, just as all other methods you already discovered. The only way to load an image on such a site is to use an allowed src which is `data:` in this case (you'll read the image contents into a Data URI and pass it to the content script). However, some sites forbid even `data:` so the universal method is to modify the site's Content-Security-Policy HTTP header using chrome.webRequest API or better show your UI in an extension iframe exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: How would I go about viewing the policy for a domain in order to see which of these attempts might work (other than modifying my own code)?

Comment: An extension can use chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived to monitor the request for the main site URL using `types: ['main_frame']` filter. To view the CSP header in devtools you can switch to the network panel and reload the page.